# When using HTML and CSS, how can I apply a class to a field that is already read-only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, readonly-attribute

Here's my dilemma:  I have jQuery code with an if-statement that applies a specific class to an element based on the value selected on a page where the user is filling out a form.  I also built another form where a user can view the details of a form that has already been filled out.  When the details page is displayed, most of the class is applied, but the grey "read-only" background overwrites the background color from the original class.  I don't really want to go into the bootstrap files and adjust the read-only background color code if I can avoid it.  How can I apply the full class (including the background color) to an element that is read-only?

Snippet of code from the "Create" page:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Question1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Question1, new[] { new SelectListItem() { Text = "Pass", Value = "Pass" }, new SelectListItem() { Text = "Fail", Value = "Fail" }, new SelectListItem() { Text = "NA", Value = "NA" } }, "Select an option", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control text-box centerline", @onchange = "updateEscalationsListeningScore()", id = "question1Answer" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Question1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

jQuery from the "Create" page:

```
if (Q1Answer === "Pass") {
        $('#question1Answer').addClass("correctListeningAnswer").removeClass("incorrectListeningAnswer").removeClass("naListeningAnswer");
        Q1Score = 3;
        Q1PotentialPoints = 3;
    }
    else if (Q1Answer === "Fail") {
        $('#question1Answer').addClass("incorrectListeningAnswer").removeClass("correctListeningAnswer").removeClass("naListeningAnswer");
        Q1Score = 0;
        Q1PotentialPoints = 3;
    }
    else if (Q1Answer === "NA") {
        $('#question1Answer').addClass("naListeningAnswer").removeClass("incorrectListeningAnswer").removeClass("correctListeningAnswer");
        Q1Score = 0;
        Q1PotentialPoints = 0;
    }
    else {
        $('#question1Answer').removeClass("correctListeningAnswer").removeClass("incorrectListeningAnswer").removeClass("naListeningAnswer");
        Q1Score = 3;
        Q1PotentialPoints = 3;
    }
```

---

Snippet of code from the "Details" page:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Question1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Question1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control text-box centerline", id = "question1Answer", @readonly = "readonly" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Question1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

jQuery from the "Details" page:

```
        if (Q1Answer === "Pass") {
        $('#question1Answer').addClass("correctListeningAnswer").removeClass("incorrectListeningAnswer").removeClass("naListeningAnswer");
        Q1Score = 3;
        Q1PotentialPoints = 3;
    }
    else if (Q1Answer === "Fail") {
        $('#question1Answer').addClass("incorrectListeningAnswer").removeClass("correctListeningAnswer").removeClass("naListeningAnswer");
        Q1Score = 0;
        Q1PotentialPoints = 3;
    }
    else if (Q1Answer === "NA") {
        $('#question1Answer').addClass("naListeningAnswer").removeClass("incorrectListeningAnswer").removeClass("correctListeningAnswer");
        Q1Score = 0;
        Q1PotentialPoints = 0;
    }
    else {
        $('#question1Answer').removeClass("correctListeningAnswer").removeClass("incorrectListeningAnswer").removeClass("naListeningAnswer");
        Q1Score = 3;
        Q1PotentialPoints = 3;
    }
```

---

CSS

```
.correctListeningAnswer {
background-color: #c6efce;
color: #006100;}

.incorrectListeningAnswer {
background-color: #ffc7ce;
color: #9c0006;}

.naListeningAnswer {
background-color: #ffeb9c;
color: #9c5700;}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Cory

Comment: `I don't really want to go into the bootstrap files and adjust the read-only background color code if I can avoid it.` - That is where you add your own CSS file on top of it and overwrite the style you need to change based on your specific scenarios.

Comment: Learn about the cascade in CSS, and learn about `!important`.

Comment: @Jason, please, let's teach people to avoid using `!important` if they can. Writing rules more specific than Bootstrap's should do the trick.

Comment: The only problem with changing read-only in bootstrap is that I use read-only in other pages and I need it to look the way it looks by default.

I have my own custom style sheet that I've loaded into the project (which is where the CSS code is that's listed above).  I was hoping there was some type of syntax that I just didn't know about that would allow me to apply my specific class...if that makes sense.

Comment: I didn't say "Use important", I told him to learn about it. Yes, it should be used sparingly, but there are times when it is needed or a good idea. If your page includes multiple CSS files, the CSS written by you, and additional CSS that go with software written by other parties, you may want some of your CSS marked !important to "guarantee" it will not be overridden by CSS from other included files. I thought it was more helpful that "Learn to write clean CSS!"

Comment: Cory, then you need to be more specific. You get classes, right? So, you're going to need to have a selector more specific that Bootstrap's. Use the dev console to see the Bootstrap selector, and add your class.

Or, you know, for page specific elements, you could just use `!important`.

`#container p {color: blue} p.red {color: red}`

`<div id="container"><p class="red">Red</p></div>`

Your "red" container is still going to be blue. The first selector is more specific. So, you need to rewrite that as `#container p.red {color: red}` to do it the right way.

Comment: @JasonMaggard Even in the case of using other vendor CSS files you should always be able to overwrite, unless they also use `!important` and in that case it shows the whole problem with using it to begin with and you stop using that third party vendor's CSS files. I found when ever we feel to use `!important` we are not doing it right. .. and mentioning `!important` is never more helpful as it always ends up being more harmful than a rock in the foreface :/

Comment: Well, I'll leave this question to you then Nope. Have a great day.

Comment: Step 1: Identify where the currently applied style comes from (dev tools). It is likely a rule that uses the attribute selector to specifically target the readonly attribute, so copy&paste the matching portion. Step 2, since you say you want this on a specific page only, check what makes it or the surrounding DOM structure identifiable - such as a specific class on the body element, or a container element closer to this specific form instance. Combine with the selector from step 1 in your own stylesheet.

Comment: @CBroe, take a look at my answer.  Your step-by-step instructions really helped me out.  Thank you!

Comment: Please see: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

Thank you, everyone, for the information.  I researched a few things that you guys all suggested and it looks like I was able to get it to work.  What's frustrating is that the answer was really simple, and the way I was able to get there was by using CBroe's method.  I just had to add this to my CSS file:

```
.correctListeningAnswer[readonly] {
background-color: #c6efce;
color: #006100;
}

.incorrectListeningAnswer[readonly] {
background-color: #ffc7ce;
color: #9c0006;
}

.naListeningAnswer[readonly] {
background-color: #ffeb9c;
color: #9c5700;
}
```

I appreciate all of your help!

Comment: You can mark your question as solved by clicking the checkmark next to your answer :-)

Comment: Thank you.  I tried to already but it says I can't for 2 days.  I'll come back to it and do that.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make the field `readonly`, make it `disabled`. Then your background will work.

Here's an example:

```css
input {
  background-color:#ffc;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" disabled>
```

Or (and I personally think this is the better approach), don't use a form field to display information. Grab the data from the initial form and then display it in more semantically correct elements, like `span`, which aren't editable in the first place.

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.getElementById("dataOut").textContent = document.getElementById("dataIn").value;
});
```

```html
<input id="dataIn">
<button type="button">Simulate a submit</button>
<span id="dataOut"></span>
```

As a last resort, you could always make your class selector more specific than the Bootstrap selectors, so that yours will take precedence.

Comment: I actually tried that prior to posting this, but disabled reacted the same way as read-only.  The only difference is that disabled shows a different icon when hovering over the element.

Comment: @Cory See my updated answer with my suggested second approach.

Comment: This answer should take Bootstrap styles into account, which it doesn't.

Comment: @Justastudent The OP has stated that he does not want to modify the Bootstrap CSS, so the answer need not/shouldn't deal with that.

Comment: Modifying Bootstrap CSS is different from writing rules specific enough to overrule Bootstrap's. The latter can still be done in a custom CSS file and is precisely the way to go for OP, I believe.

Comment: I did read the part you edited in right after my first comment, be it coincidental or not. The part that's not specific at all and likely won't help OP because it doesn't say *how* that should be done. Something along the lines of CBroe's comment on the question is what I had in mind. Of course, all of my comments take nothing away from your answer being valuable. I'm just saying it could be more specific.